# swift unable to parse php data

Tags: php, ios, swift3

I have been trying to fetch certain values from database through my `postString`, but it doesn't return any value. Php is tested and its working fine, any help would be appreciated. Below is the code.

```
import UIKit

class DisplayDetailedViewController: UIViewController {

    var role = String()
    var date = String()
    var city = String()
    var mark_ref = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func getData(){
        let myUrl = URL(string:"http://xxxxxx.co.in/xxxxx/show_report1.php")

        var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "city=\(city)&date=\(date)&market_rep=\(mark_ref)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    if error != nil{
                        print("error is\(String(describing: error))")
                    }
                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                        if let parseJSON = json {

                            let myBoard : String!
                            myBoard = parseJSON["success"] as! String?

                            print(myBoard)
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
            } 
        }
        task.resume()   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the expected JSON response in your question so that we can help parsing it. Some general advise: `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not needed, `URLSession.shared.dataTask` is already an async function. Don't use `NSDictionary` in `Swift`, but use its native `Swift` counterpart, `Dictionary`.

Comment: add the json response

Answer (score 0):

Try 1: Replace below line (NSDictionary)

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

Try 2: Replace below line (NSArray)

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray
```

Try 3: Replace below line (NSString)

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray
```

**Also try to options: .mutableContainers -> options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments**

Comment: NSArray and NSString both tried. But it gives conversion error

Comment: if let parseJSON = json {
                            
                            let myBoard : String!
                            myBoard = parseJSON["success"] as! String //this states cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'
                            
                            print(myBoard)

Comment: let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? Int